# why I cant assign specific cpu number to a process in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I defined it in nextflow.config like:

```
process.executor = 'sge'
process.clusterOptions = { "-clear -cwd -l vf=20g,num_proc=24  -binding linear:24 -P W21P0024 -q mgi.q"}
```

and in a separate process,

```
process A {
  cpus 1
  memory '1 GB'
  
  input:
  etc...
}
```

but it still use 24 cpus like the setting in the config file. how to correctly set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the [sge](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#sge) executor tries to return a list of directives to use, the [clusterOptions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#clusteroptions), if any,  will be applied last<sup>[1](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v23.04.0/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/executor/SgeExecutor.groovy#L29-L80)</sup>. I suspect these override existing ones, including `-l slots=1` which is what your process *A* will try to use to ask for one cpu. I think in the first instance, perhaps try using a more simplified configuration. Note that the `clusterOptions` directive does *not* need to be a closure:

```
process {
    executor = 'sge'
    clusterOptions = "-P W21P0024"
    queue = "mgi.q"
}
```